# Is 'to commute on foot' grammatically right?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, collocations

Is it okay to say, 'He usually *commutes on foot* and hence he always gets 10,000 steps by the end of the day'? Do *commute* and *on foot* match?

In my effort to get an answer to this question, I googled the phrase and received some not convincing material; I opened the dictionary and found no mistake in the phrase in question. Now I need to get some judgemental feedback from experts at English.

Comment: Please provide us with the information you describe as "not convincing", with links and explain why it gives you doubts. Also, what dictionary did you consult, for example? Again, a link, and an explanation of what yoh mean by finding "no mistake". What makes you doubt that your sentence is ok? It's not explicit.

Answer (score 3):

**To commute** is usually used to mean the action of going to and from work every day, with an implication that it is an appreciable distance, and that some form of transport is involved, such as car or train.  "Do you live nearby?", "No, I have to commute."

However, you certainly can override the implications: "I'm so lucky, commuting only takes 90 seconds as I live above the shop."

Your example is perfectly fine, if slightly unusual.

The most ordinary way to say it would be:

- He goes to work by foot / on foot ...
- He walks to work ...

Answer (score 2):

Commuting means "travelling to and from a particular place. Usually traveling to and from work".  It usually is used to talk about travelling by car, bus or train to work.

It could be used to mean walking to work, but if you can walk to work, the distance can't be so great, and you might not consider it to be "travelling" or "commuting". Nevertheless, some UK councils (for example) encourage people to commute on foot or by bike. Saying "I commute to work on foot" is not incorrect and has some natural use.

On the other hand, it is also natural to say "I walk to work, so I don't have to commute".  So it is probably better to say "He walks to work and so always gets 10000 steps by the end of the day."